# How to have the same subView in different ViewControllers in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, ios7

I have 1 subView that should be visible in two different View Controllers in my app (it is a main button in my app with a badge that shows new messages and other relevant information to the user).

What is the best way to achieve this?
Do I have to duplicate the subView in both View Controllers?

Comment: create the subclass of UIView and add your custom code for that view. Add as a subview to your ViewControllers.

Comment: how about creating a shared view,this view appears in all controllers with your updates

Comment: Why not adding it to the navigationBar if it's only a button ?
Otherwise you can try to add it as a subview of the Window (in this case I think that you will have to use `bringSubviewToFront:`)

Answer (score 0):

UIView's addSubview

addSubview:
Adds a view to the end of the receiver’s list of subviews.

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view
  Parameters
  view
  The view to be added. After being added, this view appears on top of any other subviews.
  Discussion
  This method establishes a strong reference to view and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.

Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.

So don't try to do that .

Answer (score 0):

You should simply have two instances of the view that look the same and have them in the same location.

You might want to have central creation method (that also updates all buttons) and target for this button.

Answer (score 0):

Create Your SubView`s CustomView And respectively add the view to your view controllers ,then save the information with NSUserdefualts  in one viewController and get it from another ViewController.